# Error when load db dump (cross platform)

Tags: sybase, dump

After a Sybase (15.0.3) compress dump a database on the original platform - Solaris Sparc 64 - with all the required steps (even the quiesce step), I have tried to load it on my Sybase (15.7) Solaris x64 (running under vmware), [equal page sizes on both systems !!!] and I got this error:

```
1> load database wfcv2  from "compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump"
2> go
Backup Server session id is: 28. Use this value when executing the
'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change
request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.132.1.1: Attempting to open byte stream device:
'compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000'
Backup Server: 4.177.2.1: The database page size of 2048 bytes obtained from ASE
is different from the database page size of -1024 bytes read from the dump
header. The LOAD session must exit.
Backup Server: 1.14.2.2: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Backup Server: 6.32.2.3: compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000: volume not
valid or not requested (server: , session id: 28.)
Backup Server: 1.14.2.4: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Msg 8009, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'MYSERVER', Line 1:
Error encountered by Backup Server.  Please refer to Backup Server messages for
details.
```

Sugestions ?

> Question from PHILL: Can you post the output of: load database wfcv2
>   from "compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" with headeronly and load
>   database wfcv2 from "compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" with
>   listonly=full – Phil

```
1> load database wfcv2 from "compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" with headeronly
2> go
Backup Server session id is: 31. Use this value when executing the
'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change
request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.132.1.1: Attempting to open byte stream device:
'compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000'
Backup Server: 4.177.2.1: The database page size of 2048 bytes obtained from ASE
is different from the database page size of -1024 bytes read from the dump
header. The LOAD session must exit.
Backup Server: 1.14.2.2: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Msg 8009, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'MYSERVER', Line 1:
Error encountered by Backup Server.  Please refer to Backup Server messages for
details.
1>
2>
3> load database wfcv2 from "compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" with listonly=full
4> go
Backup Server session id is: 33. Use this value when executing the
'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change
request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.22.1.1: Option LISTONLY is not valid for device
'compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000'.
Msg 8009, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'MYSERVER', Line 3:
Error encountered by Backup Server.  Please refer to Backup Server messages for
details.
1>
2>
3>

Backup Server messages
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apr 12 11:38:00 2012: Backup Server: 2.23.1.1: Connection from Server MYSERVER on Host MyMachine with HostProcid 3776.
Apr 12 11:38:00 2012: Backup Server: 4.132.1.1: Attempting to open byte stream device: 'compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000'
Apr 12 11:38:00 2012: Backup Server: 4.177.2.1: The database page size of 2048 bytes obtained from ASE is different from the database
 page size of -1024 bytes read from the dump header. The LOAD session must exit.
Apr 12 11:38:00 2012: Backup Server: 1.14.2.2: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD session must exit.
Apr 12 11:38:18 2012: Backup Server: 2.23.1.1: Connection from Server MYSERVER on Host MyMachine with HostProcid 3776.
Apr 12 11:38:18 2012: Backup Server: 4.22.1.1: Option LISTONLY is not valid for device 'compress::1::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000'.
```

> Question/comments from PHILL: Actually, I think it's your syntax. The
>   -1024 block size thing is a red herring. Try: load database wfcv2 from "compress::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" - Which directory is
>   20120412_wfcv2_zdump in? Is it really in the root (/) directory on
>   your box? If not, alter the path. – Phil

1) I've tried your suggestion and got the same error !

2) Because the machine where I am trying to load the dump, is my test machine (and I don't have any more space available anywhere ...), I am using / (root) location to place dump file for load. Yes, it is not the correct thing to do, but as I have stated "no free space available !".

> Question/comment from PHILL:   The LOAD syntax is incorrect.
>
> You're not supposed to specify the compression level between the pairs
>   of: characters in the LOAD DATABASE command.
>
> Assuming your dump file is on the local filesystem at
>   /20120412_wfcv2_zdump, your load command should be:
>
> 1> load database wfcv2  from "compress::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" 
>   2> go

Sybase recommends the native "compression = compress_level" option as preferred over the older "compress::compression_level" option. If you use the native option for dump database, you do not need to use "compress::compression_level" when loading your database.

in: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands64.htm

As stated, sybase recommends!

I know that the load syntax is correct and works - from my personal experience. Yesterday  was able to load others BDs from the same source server to MyMachine. Only this DB that is over 10 GB space (+/- 2GB compressed ...), is causing problems...

> Question/comment from PHILL:    Are you sure you got the same error?
>   Is the filename correct? What's the output of ls -al
>   /20120412_wfcv2_zdump ? You might need to chmod 777
>   /20120412_wfcv2_zdump it – Phil

1) Yes the name is correct !

2) It isn't a permissions issue. I am using root user for everything (yes, it is not the correct thing to do, but as I have stated this is my personal test machine !).

> Question/comment from PHILL:   Ok, I've read the manual again. The
>   load format is definitely load database wfcv2 from
>   "compress::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump" for compressed volumes and not
>   "compress::1::/ ... - Please post the output of the error generated by
>   this so I can see (I know you stated you tried it, but I'd like to
>   have a look anyway). The documentation even states not to put the
>   compression level "1". One last thing - did you ftp the file in ASCII
>   mode by accident? – Phil

OK !  Here it goes !
... And the answer to "did you ftp the file in ASCII"   is NO !  Thanks anyway !

```
1>
2>
3> load database wfcv2 from "compress::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump"
4> go
Backup Server session id is: 35. Use this value when executing the
'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change
request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.132.1.1: Attempting to open byte stream device:
'compress::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000'
Backup Server: 4.177.2.1: The database page size of 2048 bytes obtained from ASE
is different from the database page size of -1024 bytes read from the dump
header. The LOAD session must exit.
Backup Server: 1.14.2.2: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Backup Server: 6.32.2.3: compress::/20120412_wfcv2_zdump::000: volume not valid
or not requested (server: , session id: 35.)
Backup Server: 1.14.2.4: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Msg 8009, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'MYMACHINE', Line 3:
Error encountered by Backup Server.  Please refer to Backup Server messages for
details.
```

I believe that the answer to all this issue can be the simplest answer: - Data corruption ... !

Just in case, I´ll do another dump, and try to load it again !

Phill, thanks for you time !  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ---
>
> Ok !  Let me describe how this issue was solved:
>
> ---

1) There was definitely a corruption issue caused by a problem with vmware tools on solaris 10.  When the network interface had high transfer/load operations (sample: copy of a 2 GB DB ....), it just stoped working, in the middle of the operation. To put the interface working again, I had to disconnect and connect the network interface again (in the vmware interface !).
Basically, I had to unistall vmware tools on solaris virtual machine.
There was one catch, the highest transfer rates that could be achieved was about 300 Kb. Basically I could take hours to perform a simple ftp transfer of a 2 GB database, but there wasn´t any corruption at all.
How to prove/test that there is/inst´t any corruption. I just packed (on the source machine) the database dump into a tar file (yes, an extra 20kb), but after the download complete, on the target server, I was able to untar the file, and if the untar operation was sucessfull that proved that there wasn´t any corruption on the file that was just transfered.

2) After being sure that the dump was ok, I got a diferent error:

```
Apr 17 14:24:20 2012: Backup Server: 4.188.1.1: Database wfcv2: 158936 kilobytes (1%) LOADED.
Apr 17 14:24:47 2012: Backup Server: 4.188.1.1: Database wfcv2: 303212 kilobytes (2%) LOADED.
Apr 17 14:25:16 2012: Backup Server: 4.188.1.1: Database wfcv2: 447104 kilobytes (3%) LOADED.
Apr 17 14:25:39 2012: Backup Server: 4.124.2.1: Archive API error for device='compress::1::/data4/20120413_wfcv2_zdump::000': Vendor application name=Compress API, Library version=1, API routine=syb_read(), Message=syb_read: gzread() error=0, msg=Error 0
Apr 17 14:25:39 2012: Backup Server: 4.124.2.1: Archive API error for device='compress::1::/data4/20120413_wfcv2_zdump::000': Vendor application name=Compress API, Library version=1, API routine=syb_close(), Message=syb_close: gzclose() error=-3 msg=Input/output buffer is corrupt
Apr 17 14:25:39 2012: Backup Server: 6.32.2.3: compress::1::/data4/20120413_wfcv2_zdump::000: volume not valid or not requested (server: , session id: 20.)
Apr 17 14:25:39 2012: Backup Server: 1.14.2.4: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD session must exit.
```

> Ok !  Sybase configuration issues !

I had to configure some parameters that were related to load operations, such as:

number of large i/o buffers -> 32
max memory

> And a Solaris issue !

I also had to adjust  the Operating System Shared Memory to the sybase engine ... !

And I finally was able to load the DB (size > 2.1 GB) !

;-)    Cheers !